# Chrome 66: Date.parse() gives unexpected results for invalid ISO 8601 dates

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Output from Chrome 66 debug console with Hongkong timezone:

Valid date:

```
new Date('2018-06-30')
Sat Jun 30 2018 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)
```

Invalid date gives T+1 value!

```
new Date('2018-06-31')
Sun Jul 01 2018 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)
```

Finally... and invalid date error.

```
new Date('2018-06-32')
Invalid Date
```

Why does June 31 give T+1?

Comment: JavaScript's `Date` is awfully crippled. For any kind of serious date/time manipulation, take a look at the `moment` library instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript `Date` object is happy to handle unit rollover for you, that's all that's going on with the `2018-06-31` example — it's handling the rollover from June 30th to July 1st.

It doesn't do that for the `2018-06-32` example because `32` is an invalid value for the days field (whereas 31 isn't, it's just that June only has 30 days). The spec defines the valid ranges for the parts of the date/time string [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format), where we can see it says the valid values for the day of the month are 01 to 31 inclusive.

---

It's probably worth noting that the parsing of that ISO-8601-derived format (it isn't ISO-8601, quite) if you don't include a timezone indicator has a checkered history, sadly. ES5 specified ISO-8601 but got the meaning of the absense of a timezone indicator wrong (it said it should mean UTC, but ISO-8601 says it means local time); then ES2015 tried to fix that, but conforming to ES2016's rules would have broken a substantial amount of real-world code; and so it wasn't stabilized until ES2016, which says: Date-only forms (like yours) without a timezone indicator are UTC, date/time forms without one are local time. (It's been fine for years if you *do* include a timezone indicator.)

Comment: To quote from MDN: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

You might want to use a library like moment.js for better cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: @DanieleTorino - That would be a better comment on the *question* than on the answer.

Comment: Maybe. I didn't want to pollute the thread with a new answer since you already gave the correct one. It was merely thought as an addendum.